# where to store the file used in FileInputStream

Tags: android, android-file

If I want to use FileInputStream to read a file with its file name in my android application, where should I save the file. Can I save it in res/raw?

Answer (score 1):

You can't save it in res/raw at runtime you can save it in sdcard or in cache dir.

In order to save a file to the SD card you must have permissions to write to the card. You need to add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Next you open a file stream, write to it, and close it wherever you want to do that in code:

```
String filename = "filename.txt";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] data = new String("data to write to file").getBytes();
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: however I have prepare the files, how can I put them into the SD card.

Comment: if you are using the above code then the file will be on sdcard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the file inside your .apk and read it at runtime, you should put it in `assets/` folder in your project and you may use:

```
InputStream istream = context.getAssets().open(FILE_NAME);
```

to reach it. If, however, you are looking for method to read files from /sdcard, see the other answer.